# Different Solution for $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\tan(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}$

Tags: definite-integrals

I Believe that I have the optimal solution, using the fact that: 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\tan(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}{\sin(x)^{\sqrt{2}}+\cos(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}{\sin(x)^{\sqrt{2}}+\cos(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}$$

and the noticing that

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}{\sin(x)^{\sqrt{2}}+\cos(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}{\sin(x)^{\sqrt{2}}+\cos(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}=\pi/2.$$

These together imply that the solution is $\pi/4$.

**remark:** the $\sqrt{2}$ is unimportant, for the more general $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\tan(x)^{\alpha}}$,  my solution is invariant for any  $\alpha \in {\mathbb{R}^{+}}$.

However, had I been given 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\tan(x)}$$
I maybe would have actually attempted a solution by more standard methods, in order to find a closed expression for the integral. My method does not give a closed form, does anyone know a way to find one?

I was given a possible alternative route:
Let $$F(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\tan(x)^{\alpha}},$$

and to differentiate with respect to $\alpha$, yet I'm not sure why this is helpful or how that kind of method "goes."

Comment: This is a dumb question, but why is $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}{\sin(x)^{\sqrt{2}}+\cos(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}{\sin(x)^{\sqrt{2}}+\cos(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}=\pi/2$ true?

Comment: @William: the two involved integrals are equal by the substitution $x\mapsto\frac{\pi}{2}-x$, and they clearly add to $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}1\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$. For the OP: you have a wonderful solution by symmetry, why do you need a lengthier alternative?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think what OP is trying to ask is to find a general procedure valid for a more general class of exponents $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$ besides $\sqrt{2}$. I might be misinterpreting however.

Comment: @William: the OP is clearly well aware that the same approach works  for any positive real exponent, as written in his **remark**.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio OK then I don't understand the question at all either

Comment: @William The OP is saying that if he saw the case where $a=1$, he wouldn't have tought of doing this trick, and might have gotten stuck when standard methods didn't work. He is asking how he could do it without resorting to such "tricks"

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I am proud of the solution by symmetry, and I like it a lot. I am however trying to work on different techniques of integration. It is not so much that I care about finding a *better* solution to this problem, but I'd like to be made aware of different ways to approach this question, particularly methods that are more extendable to other types of integrals. I hope that is reason enough to ask this question.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee 2/3 answers to that question are the same as I've posted above. The remaining answer boils down to the second part of Jack's solution. I would be glad to merge the two questions, if we can preserve Jack's answer, which I think is both different and interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Differentiation under the integral sign is another viable alternative, but the trick is pretty the same:
$$ \frac{dF}{d\alpha}=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(-\log\tan x\right)\frac{\tan(x)^\alpha}{(1+\tan(x)^\alpha)^2}\,dx\\=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\log\tan x+\log\cot x\right)\frac{\tan(x)^\alpha}{(1+\tan(x)^\alpha)^2}\,dx =\color{red}{0}$$
gives that $F(\alpha)$ is constant over $\mathbb{R}^+$, and
$$ \lim_{\alpha\to 0^+} F(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{2}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}}.$$

---

An alternative proof may go through the following lines. We have:
$$ F(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{(1+u^2)(1+u^\alpha)}.$$
Through the substitution $u=v^{-1}$ we have:
$$ F(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{u^{\alpha}\,du}{(1+u^2)(1+u^{\alpha})}$$
so:
$$ F(\alpha)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{1+u^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: Question to ensure I'm understanding, why do you examine $\lim_{\alpha \to 0_{+}}F(\alpha)$? Is it because the integral is definite, meaning that you can distribute inside the integral, and that limit evaluates to $1/2$, giving the desired answer? Can you direct me to more examples of where this method is of interest? **very** interesting! +1 btw

Comment: @AndresMejia: once we know that our function is constant, we just need to evaluate it at some point. $\alpha=0$ seems to grant an easy evaluation, but it is on the boundary of the domain, hence we consider the limit as $\alpha\to 0^+$ that indeed *is* easy to evaluate.

Comment: Ah, i saw the first part of your comment, but I hadnt thought closely about $0_+$, an obvious but important point, thank you

Comment: At the risk of pestering, do you know of other instances where this method is useful? Thanks

Comment: @AndresMejia: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936620/how-to-find-this-double-summation is a famous exercise that involves a *symmetry trick*, and you may find others here on MSE by just searching for the two magical words.

Comment: Ah, i was referring to the $F (\alpha) $ trick, i will look at all the symmetry arguments though, they are very cute :) much obliged

Comment: @AndresMejia: have a look at this PDF, too: https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Feynman.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Let $$I= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+\tan x}$$
You can  replace $x \rightarrow \pi/2 -x$ in the integral to get
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+\cot x}$$
$$\implies I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan xdx}{1+\tan x}$$
Adding this to the original integral gives 
$$I=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: This is not any different from my solution, $\frac{1}{1+\cot(x)}=\frac{\sin}{\cos+\sin}$... I won't downvote, but I don't think this answer adds anything to the current list of methods